# Set Difference proof verification

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory, proof-writing

New to sets therefore unsure of if the element method has been correctly and am unable to complete my proof

For all sets $A,B,C$, if $A-B=A-C$, then $(A \cap B)- C = \varnothing$

My attempt at a proof:

[image]

I'm not sure where to go from here. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Thus $x \in A \setminus C$ but $x \notin A \setminus B$ ...

Answer (score 1):

Hint:
$$ A \setminus B = A \setminus C \quad \iff \quad A \cap \overline B = A \cap \overline C$$

$$(A \cap B) \setminus C = (A \cap B) \cap \overline C = (A \cap \overline C) \cap B = (A \cap \overline B) \cap B = A \cap (\overline B \cap B) = A \cap \emptyset = \emptyset$$

Answer (score 0):

Thus x∈A∖Cx∈A∖C but x∉A∖Bx∉A∖B ... – @MauroALLEGRANZA