# Element method on set inequality proof-verification

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory, proof-verification

With respect to the following question:

Prove that For all sets $A,B,C$,  if $(A \cap B) - C= \varnothing$, then $A-B = A-C$

Does the following proof verify it?
[image]

Specifically, does the existence of element $x$ in $A$ and $B$ and $C$ also prove that $A-B = A-C$

Comment: "Does the following proof verify it?"  What proof?  The fourth line is not a proof in the slightest.  How does this differ from your [previous question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1976232/set-difference-proof-verification)?  If you wish for more clarification on the problem, you should say so in your already open question instead of opening a new one.

Comment: sorry @JMoravitz added the question before adding the proof

Comment: "Let there exist an element $x\in C$"  But... this isn't always true.  There exists a set with no elements where you would not be able to take any such $x$.

Comment: No @JMoravitz It is the converse of that question, so isn't logically equivalent to it.

Comment: $(A \cap B) - C = \phi$ does not mean that $(A \cap B ) = C$, it actually means that $A \cap B \subset C$.

Comment: Before investing too much effort into a proof ask yourself whether you think it might possibly be false first.  I can come up with several examples of $A$ and $B$ where $A\cap B=\emptyset$, and we know that $\emptyset \setminus C=\emptyset$ regardless of what $C$ is...

Comment: A final issue with your "proof" is going from "$x\in A$ and $x\in B$ and $x\in C$" to the next line "So, $x\in A-B$ and $x\in A-C$."  This also is false.  In fact, if $x$ is an element of $A,B$ and $C$ then $x$ is **not** an element of $A-B$ and is not an element of $A-C$.  Further, even if you were able to justify that step, it would not imply that the two sets are equal.

Comment: Thanks for ripping my proof apart :), learned a lot , So it is false then if A={1} B={2} and C=null set.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let us correct your proof.

First of all, the definition of $A-B$ is the set of elements contained in $A$ which are not in $B$. Therefore, if $X-Y = \phi$, it does not mean $X=Y$, rather that all elements of $X$ are also in $Y$, or that $X \subset Y$.

With this in mind, our aim is to show the following:$A-B=A-C$, given $(A\cap B) - C = \phi$, which translates to $A \cap B \subset C$.

I have no clue what you did after that, but let me proceed any way.

For this, let $x \in A - C$. Then, $x \in A, x \notin C$. Therefore, $x \notin A \cap B$, therefore $x \notin B$, therefore $x\in A - B$. So $A - C \subset A-B$.

Now, let $x \in A -B$. As it turns out, $A-B \nsubseteq A-C$ in general. The logic is simple. If $x \in A - B$, then $x \notin A \cap B$. But then, $A \cap B$ is only a *subset* of C, it is not equal to $C$. Therefore, we cannot conclude from here that $x \notin C$, so $x \in A-C$.

For example, let $A = \{ 1,2,3\}, B = \{ 2,3,4\}, C = \{ 1,2,3,7\}$. Then, $A - B = \{1\}$, and $A-C = \phi$, so they are not equal. We can see that $A \cap B = \{2,3\}$, which is a strict subset of $C$.

Comment: So the whole proof was false to begin with. Thanks.

Comment: @SajSeesSound You are welcome.